# Install Apache Spark on Windows 11

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, windows-11

I installed Apache Spark 3.2 and Hadoop 3 in my Windows 11. I have also Python 3.8 installed.

When I tried to call Pyspark on my cmd. I got this message:

> Missing Python executable 'python3', defaulting to 'C:\Spark\bin..'
> for SPARK_HOME environment variable. Please install Python or specify
> the correct Python executable in PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON or
> PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to detect SPARK_HOME safely.

What should I do? Can I just make changes in my environment variable? If yes, which changes?

Comment: set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` as `python`  in user variables. and restart your machine, then try